# Programmatically created products doesn't show on WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I created a cron job to fetch wholesaler product list and insert them into the database.

But when I create a product in this way, it's doesn't show in the shop, only in the admin. After I enter into the edit page of any product and click the save button without make changes on the product, this product apear in the shop.

What would be the problem with the products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When inserting a product to the database, If you want it to appear on front end, you need in **`wp_posts`** table to set **`'post_status'`** key with a value of **`'publish'`**. 
>   **Without it, it doesn't appear on front end.**
>
> Also the **`'post_date'`** and **`'post_date_gmt'`** need to have a date lower than **"today"**…

Check also in **`wp_postmeta`** table that you are also setting:

- **`'_visibility'`** key to **`'visible'`** value
- **`'_stock_status'`** key to **`'instock'`** value
- **`'_stock'`** with some value…

**Once done, your products should appear on shop page**, without editing them.

Comment: Yes, you must ensure that all the meta created by the [product meta `save()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/14eeee15ee40ae58afbc617a001323cc9ac16636/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L770) function is reproduced by your own methods. You could also consider using the API to [add a product](https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product).

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue, In my case it was language issue, we installed polylang, when we import product using API we missed to set the default language.

For poly-lang i added below code.

```
global $polylang;


$language_code='de';
     
if (function_exists('pll_set_post_language')) {                
      pll_set_post_language($post_id, $language_code);
   } else {
      error_log(print_r($post_id . ' poly-lang not found!'));
   }
```